# MYSQL Single Table Count() show even if it = NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking all over google - I may just be to stupid to comprehend the answer.

I have a table in mysql - issues.

```
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   |
| status      | varchar(255)  | YES  |
+-------------+---------------+------+
```

Each issue have a status.

I am trying to get a select to count all the issues and list them by status:

```
SELECT status,COUNT(*) as 'total' FROM issues WHERE (DATE(logged_at) >= <INSERT RANGE> ) GROUP BY status
```

There are 5 different statuses -

```
Report
Not Fixed
Fixed
Escalated
Referred
```

The trouble is - my select only shows the Status if the count > 0. How do I show all states even if count = null ?

I've tried IFNULL but no luck. I've also seen people talk about left join solutions, but that was multiple table problems.

Comment: This *is* a multiple table problem.  You need one table that lists the statuses, and one table with the data.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is what you have crossed into: a `LEFT JOIN` from a table that has all these 5 statuses. If you don't have such a table, you can create it as permament or on the fly (every time you need it):

```
SELECT 
    st.status
  , COUNT(issues.status) AS total
FROM 
    ( SELECT 'Active' AS status UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Inactive' UNION ALL
      ... 
      SELECT 'Super'
    ) AS st
  LEFT JOIN 
    issues 
      ON  issues.status = st.status
      AND issues.logged_at >= ?        -- no reason to use DATE() function here
GROUP BY st.status ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need an additional table (e.g. called statuses) that stores a list of all statuses, i.e. one field of same type as in your issues table and make sure you put index on the field.

Then the following SQL should do the trick:

```
select statuses.status,count(issues.id) from issues right join statuses on issues.status=statuses.status group by statuses.status
```

The advantage of the additional table is, should you ever decide to have another status, all you need to do is add it to the table without having to change any of the existing SQL statements.